# Split text string from a certain percentage

Tags: python, text, split

I need to split a text from a certain score. For example the first dot after 50% of text.
Example:

```
a = 'Hello this text. It is a reference. But I like it very much, I would like to share with you everything I know. Goodbye friends.'
```

If I wanted to divide the text from the first dot after 50%, I would get:

```
'Goodbye friends.'
```

How could I get this result?

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: 'Goodbye friends.' if 50% of what ?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'Hello this text. It is a reference. But I like it very much, I would like to share with you everything I know. Goodbye friends.'

#first we get the index of the string to the half, using len function to get the total len,
#then that len is divided by 2, and using :len(a) we take the 
#the last place of the string
b = a[int(len(a) / 2):len(a)]

#with find function save in a variable the index of the first dot
#in the string saved on variable b
c = b.find(".")

#In a new variable taken the new string, using square 
#brackets we take the index of the first dot saved on variable c, and then using len 
#function we indicate the last place of the string 
d = b[c:len(b)]

print(d)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's perfect, I've also been thinking about it that way.

Comment: Would be nice to have some explanation with the answer!